# TAOCP Section 1.2.2: How can one conclude that b^x is unique from the given relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $b$ is a positive real number and $x$ is a real number such that

$$
x = n + 0.d_1d_2d_3...
$$
Where $n$ is an integer and $d_i$ is a digit between $0$ and $9$.

When b > 1, we can say

$$
b^{n + \frac{d_1}{10} + ... + \frac{d_k}{10^k}} \le b^x \lt b^{n + \frac{d_1}{10} + ... + \frac{d_k}{10^k} + \frac{1}{10^k}}
$$

Then the text says

> This defines $b^x$ as a unique positive real number, since the difference between the right and left extreme is $b^{n + d_1/10 + ... + d_k/10^k}(b^{1/10^k} - 1)$

How one can conclude that if the difference between the right and left hand side of the above inequality is $b^{n + d_1/10 + ... + d_k/10^k}(b^{1/10^k} - 1)$, it is unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unique because as $k \to \infty$, the difference between the two sides goes to zero. Namely, $(b^{1/10^k} - 1) \to 0$.

Slightly more drawn out, suppose that the number wasn't uniquely defined. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two distinct candidate numbers for $b^x$. Without loss of generality, let us suppose that $A < B$, to that in particular $B = A + \delta$ for some real number $\delta > 0$. As both $A$ and $B$ fall between the upper and lower bounds described in your question, and the difference between the upper and lower bounds goes to $0$ as $k \to \infty$, there is some $k$ in particular such that $b^{1/10^k} - 1 < \delta$. But then we cannot have that both $A$ and $B$ are candidates for $b^x$, as they differ by more than $\delta$.